# App crashes on launching Android DatePicker support in HTML5

Tags: android-datepicker

I am having a webview which launches my web pages built using html5, jquery mobile and my own custom css. The web pages have date field defined using html5 tags . When I click the date field, the datepicker pops up and when I set the date and click 'Ok' my application crashes giving null pointer exception.

Comment: You need to show the *relevant* code you're using as well as the full (red) log output from the LogCat.

Comment: I am loading an Html5 page in the WebView with the following line: <input type="date"  size =""  value="" />. I am running the app on Samsung Galaxy Tab-2. The device browser recognizes the html5 attribute type="date" and opens the device's datepicker. When I select the date from datepicker and click save I get the follow exceptions in my logcat

Comment: 01-25 12:25:38.430: D/AndroidRuntime(11911): Shutting down VM
01-25 12:25:38.430: W/dalvikvm(11911): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40be21f8)
01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: 01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):  at android.webkit.WebView$DateTimePicker.updateDate(WebView.java:6209)
01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):  at android.webkit.WebView$DateTimePicker.access$2200(WebView.java:6138)
01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):  at android.webkit.WebView$DateTimePicker$1.onDateSet(WebView.java:6266)
01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:112)

Comment: 01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: 01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)

Comment: 01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
01-25 12:25:38.438: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?